# symfony2 http_cache warmup

Tags: caching, symfony

i would like to make a cache warmup for the symfony2 http_cache.
i also would like to integrate it in the cache:warmup symfony command.

so i made a new cache warmer, registered it as service and so on.
this works so far.

the easiest way of warming the http_cache, imho, was to simply call the specific page via curl, buzz or whatever.

i placed this into the `warmup()` method, but the http_cache dir in the cache dir is somehow cleared, after calling my custom warmer.

if i place a `exit;` after my curl call in my custom warmer, the http_cache dir is there.

i experimented a bit with priority in services.xml but no success.

any ideas?